# When I am scrolling horizontally, my cell values are being changed

Tags: iphone, scroll

I am working with mdspreadview cell: https://github.com/mochidev/MDSpreadView
from above link.

When I am scrolling horizontally, `cellforrowatindexpath` method is getting called and my cell value changes.

```
  - (MDSpreadViewCell *)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)rowPath forColumnAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)columnPath
   {
     static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

MDSpreadViewCell *cell = [aSpreadView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[MDSpreadViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:MDSpreadViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
 switch (columnPath.row) {
    case 0:
    {
        radiobutton=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
        [radiobutton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [radiobutton setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        radiobutton.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];
        cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
        [cell addSubview:radiobutton];
        break;
    }
    case 1:
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.timearray objectAtIndex:rowPath.column];
        break;
        case 2:
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.firstnamearray objectAtIndex:rowPath.column];
        break;
        case 3:
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.lastnamearray objectAtIndex:rowPath.column];
        break;
        case 4:
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.agearray objectAtIndex:rowPath.column];
        break;
        case 5:
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.reasonarray objectAtIndex:rowPath.column];
        break;
        case 6:
        cell.textLabel.text=[self.statusarray objectAtIndex:rowPath.column];


    default:
      break;

}

    NSLog(@"%d,%d,%d,%d,%d,%d",rowPath.section,columnPath.section,rowPath.row,columnPath.row,rowPath.column,columnPath.column);

return cell;
  }

    - (void)spreadView:(MDSpreadView *)aSpreadView didSelectCellForRowAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)rowPath forColumnAtIndexPath:(MDIndexPath *)columnPath
 {

[spreadView deselectCellForRowAtIndexPath:rowPath forColumnAtIndexPath:columnPath animated:YES];
NSLog(@"Selected %@ x %@", rowPath, columnPath);




 }
```

When my spread view width is greater than the my view width iam getting this problem.

Then my problem is when view is loaded my button is added to first column and 4th column (case 0 and case 4),but i added it to only the first one. Please help me I was struggling for the past few days. Thank you.

Comment: make the reuse identifier to nill and try cell = [[[MDSpreadViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:MDSpreadViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nill] autorelease];

Comment: thank for ur reply,if i use ruseidentifier to nil then i am getting all of my table as a empty cells